# why do i have to reload the app after change direction from LTR to RTL in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

I use `I18nManager.forceRTL(true)` in `initialState` or `componentDidMount` life cycle but it does't work and if I reload my App, it works.

I mean I have to reload the App to see the effect, what is the reason?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's how Android works - you have to re-create your activity's layout for it to take effect.

Comment: what exactly you mean?

Comment: @VladMatvienko thanks for reply, for which kind of changes do i have to reload my App?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know as for the react native, but in pure Android you need to restart the Activity.

Answer (score 10):

**Android:**
Inside MainApplication:

1. `import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;`
2. Add these lines to onCreate():

I18nUtil.getInstance().allowRTL(this, true);

I18nUtil.getInstance().forceRTL(this, true);

**iOS:**
Inside AppDelegate:

1. `#import <React/RCTI18nUtil.h>`
2. Add these lines to applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] allowRTL:YES];

[[RCTI18nUtil sharedInstance] forceRTL:YES];

Comment: this is the correct answer please choose it as the right one.

Comment: in android find MainApplication --> project / android / app / src / main / java / com /  your_project / MainApplication.java

in ios fint AppDelegate.m --> project / ios / your_project / AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 4):

For reloading the App you can use [react-native-restart](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart)

After installing the module, you can use it like here:

```
// Add these at the top of your component file
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart';
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';

// Then use it 
...
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
RNRestart.Restart();
```

If you want to use it inside of **componentDidMount** function of your component, You need to run this code exactly once, not more:

```
// Inside of your component class
componentDidMount() {
    if(!I18nManager.isRTL) {
        I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
        RNRestart.Restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, is there anyway we could show the splashscreen, or any view for that matter the app restarts, at the moment its just shows a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RNRestart.Restart()` after `I18nManager.forceRTL(true)`. It will not close your app.